# Counting from another table [mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have one table like this:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | site_id | search_term |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       2 | apple       |
|  2 |       2 | banana      |
|  3 |       3 | cheese      |
|  4 |       1 | aubergine   |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

And another like this:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | site_id | search_term |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       2 |           1 |
|  2 |       2 |           2 |
|  3 |       2 |           1 |
|  4 |       2 |           1 |
|  5 |       3 |           3 |
|  6 |       1 |           4 |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

I want to find out how many times each search_term shows up in the 2nd table, and how many times.

In other words, from this data, if I was asking about site_id 2, I'd want this to be returned:

```
+-------------+-------+
| search_term | count |
+-------------+-------+
| apple       |     3 |
| banana      |     1 |
+-------------+-------+
```

I'm familiar with basic joins and such, as well as COUNT, but I'm not sure how to count things from another table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select t1.search_term, count(*) from t1
join t2 on t1.id = t2.search_term and t1.site_id = t2.site_id
where t1.site_id = 2
group by t1.search_term
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join the tables together, and count the number of rows in the second table:

```
select  t1.search_term
,       count(t2.id)
from    table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.search_term
group by t1.search_term
```